# Derivative Product Rule Proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

The usual proof of the product rule is:

$\begin{align*} (fg)'(x) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)}{h} \\&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x+h)g(x) + f(x+h)g(x) - f(x)g(x)}{h} \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)(g(x+h)-g(x))}{h} + \frac{g(x)(f(x+h)-f(x))}{h}\right) \tag 1 \\ &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x+h)\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} + \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}g(x)\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \tag 2 \\ &= f(x)g'(x) + g(x)f'(x).\tag 3 \end{align*}$

Why isn't that proof is usually written backwards?
Transition from $(1)$ to $(2)$ can only be done with the knowledge that corresponding parts of $(1)$ exist (same for $(2)$ to $(3)$).
Also we are supposed to show that $(fg)'$ exist and equals to $(3)$, given that $f'$ and $g'$ exist. So isn't it more clear to start with $(3)$?
To me proof above looks more like a "working backwards" sketch.

Comment: Your tags aren't visible. But you're right that the equality on line 4 should say *provided these limits exist* (and line 5 shows they do). BTW, you omitted the necessary justification that differentiability implies continuity used on line 5.

Comment: @TedShifrin, True, but I've decided to omit this in order to concentrate question on the proof direction.

Comment: The step by step evaluation of a limit is a valid proof of the existence of limit provided it ends in successful evaluation to finite or infinite limit. One does not start step by step evaluation of limit by first proving the existence of limit. The key is that each step should be based on valid rules of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree that the proof should be taught the other way round.
It is just too tempting to assume that following limit rules were used.
$$
\require{cancel}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ldots\pm\dots}{h} \overset{?}{=} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\dots}{h} \pm \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\dots}{h} \\
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ldots\cdot\dots}{h} \overset{?}{=} \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\dots}{h} \cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\dots
$$
Assuming these rules were correct one could "proof" wrongly as follows:
$$
\cancel{
\begin{align}
[f(x)\:g(x)]'
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)\:g(x+h)}{h}-
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)\:g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)}{h}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h)-
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{h}\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}g(x) \\
&= g(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)}{h}-
g(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{h}\\
&= g(x)\left[\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)}{h}-
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{h}\right]\\
&= g(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)}{h}-
\frac{f(x)}{h}\right] \\
&= g(x)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right] \\
&= g(x)\:f'(x) \\
\end{align}
}
$$
Looks perfectly alright, doesn't it? What has gone wrong?
To apply any of the limit rules, we must make sure, that the limits exist. But since we do not know the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ this is hardly possible. Especially as long as the denominator is zero the limit fraction rule cannot be applied.
$$
\lim_{x\to p}g(x)\neq0\rightarrow\lim_{x\to p}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to p}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to p}g(x)}
$$
When we approach the proof of the derivative product rule starting the other end, we reverse-apply the limit rules starting with limit expressions which are known to exist and it is plausible that the combined expression exists as well.
$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)\:g(x)+f(x)\:g'(x)
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right]g(x)+
f(x)\:\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right]
\lim_{h\to 0}g(x)+
\lim_{h\to 0}f(x)\:\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right]
\lim_{h\to 0}g(x+h)+
f(x)\:\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\:g(x+h)\right]+
\lim_{h\to0}\left[f(x)\:\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}\right] \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]\:g(x+h)}{h}+
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)\:\left[g(x+h)-g(x)\right]}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x+h)}{h}
+\frac{f(x)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x+h)
+f(x)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)\:g(x+h)-f(x)\:g(x)}{h} \\
&=(f(x)\:g(x))'
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason of doing it in the "usual order" is that we don't have to assume the answer. We are looking for it. Of course the "trick" of subtracting and adding is not easy but it is explainable. And once we have proven the product rule, with a little help the students will be able to invent the "trick" to find the derivative of a quotient of functions. I think that the idea in teaching math is finding results rather than verifying them (which as teachers we do too often).

Comment: Completely agree with you. But it seems strange to me that there is no annotation like "now that we have verified our hypothesis, the proof is given just by reversing the direction", or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. But when this proof is presented in a first year calculus class (at least in the US), most students are overwhelmed by any kind of proof already, and this kind of technical detail might serve to confuse more than enlighten.

Comment: Initially I've read it in that form in Spivak's Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I see proving the reverse more as proving IBP rather than the product rule.

Regardless, we have to assume $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exist by first principles definition from the get-go in order to say that:

$$(f(x)g(x))'=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}{h}$$
We then take the intuitive step to arrive at $(1)$ and go from there for our proof.

Comment: It seems to me that we can't justify existence of $(fg)'$ without going from $(3)$ all the way "up" (in my question).